# Trouble booting in any OS / USB disk

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

Recently, I have installed Linux MINT into a separate partition next to Windows. But then I realized that I installed the wrong version, so I deleted the partition MINT was installed on.
[image: Windows Disk Management]
Ever since, when I booted my computer, it did not boot into Windows, but rather into GRUB.

What I don't understand is:

1. Is GRUB an OS like Windows that you can boot into?
2. Where is GRUB located, and why is it loaded instead of Windows?
3. Why doesn't my USB stick show up in the list of devices in BIOS?
4. How do I fix all this?
5. Does the "Recovery Partition", "EFI System Partition", or "Basic Data Partition" have anything to do with this?

When booting into GRUB, I have to type "exit" to normally boot into windows.

Please help and let me know if you need any other information

This is the nearest thing I found by it didn't help: [Dualboot: Ubuntu not booting at all. Windows booting goes through GRUB command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1594553/dualboot-ubuntu-not-booting-at-all-windows-booting-goes-through-grub-command-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is GRUB an OS like Windows that you can boot into

No, it is not considered an OS. While there are subtle differences, you may consider it an equivalent of the Windows Boot Manager (WBM) in the GNU/Linux ecosystem.

> Where is GRUB located, and why is it loaded instead of Windows?

In the case of UEFI booting, part of it, namely the EFI executable, is located in one of the EFI system partitions. It really depends on your choice during the Mint installation (although I heard reports that it actually ignores your choices and end up using the one Windows uses anyway).

The remaining parts typically resides in `/boot`. If you do not have a dedicated partition for `/boot`, it means those parts resides in the partition/filesystem for `/` (root).

This is likely your case. Since you deleted the root partition, your grub will be left "incomplete", which results in it entering its rescue mode. Therefore, instead of seeing the grub menu, you get the grub rescue shell.

In the case of UEFI booting, it is loaded because it is registered to your UEFI firmware. A UEFI boot entry that points to the EFI executable is created during the registration, which is performed during the installation of grub (bootloader installation, i.e., `grub-install`; not  package installation; although the latter in some distro will trigger the former automatically, IIRC)

If grub UEFI boot entry has a higher priority in the UEFI boot order than others, such as the one points to the WBM, it is booted first.

> Why doesn't my USB stick show up in the list of devices in BIOS

You didn't seem to have prepared it properly for UEFI booting. Linux installation medium typically shouldn't be formatted with NTFS. Besides, it has no FAT(32)-formatted EFI system partition, so your UEFI firmware wouldn't find its bootloader's / boot manager's EFI executable.

> How do I fix all this?

Depends on exactly what you mean. If all you want to do is to make your machine boot Windows first / by default, change the boot order in your UEFI firmware setting. Optionally, delete the grub UEFI boot entry by some means (e.g., with `efibootmgr`) and clean up the files in the EFI system partition. (It's probably a directory named `mint` or so under `/EFI` of the ESP's root.)